# Update select attribute in custom_attributes via catalogProductRepositoryV1 API PUT request

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, api, repository

I'm trying to update a product with the `catalogProductRepositoryV1`.
I want to change a custom select attribute for the given product. When sending the following request:

```
{
  "product": {
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "color_armrest",
                "value": "Akoya"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "message": "Error occurred during \"custom_attributes\" processing. Attribute \"color_armrest\" has invalid value. The \"Akoya\" value's type is invalid. The \"int\" type was expected. Verify and try again.",
  "trace": null
}
```

I understand I'm supposed to insert the attributes option_id here and not the label, but how do I get it? Do I really need to use the `catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1` to fetch all attribute options and filter the id and then pass it to the product put request?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your request `value` for your `color_armrest` has to be in integer. Every option in the storefront should have an integer internally corresponding to it. This is not shown on the frontend but you can look it up by using `GET` request.